# Dynamic Dispatch with a function passed in as a parameter

Tags: python, polymorphism, dynamic-dispatch

**Example**

```
class Parent:

  def foo(self):
    print('parent')


class DerivedA(Parent):

  def foo(self):
    print('derived A')


class DerivedB(Parent):

  def foo(self):
    print('derived B')

def bar(passed_in_func):
  temp = [DerivedA(), DerivedB()]
  for derived in temp:
    passed_in_func(derived)

bar(Parent.foo)
```

**Output:**

```
parent
parent
```

**Output Desired:**

```
derived A
derived B
```

Is there any way to call the derived class' function `bar` with the following constraints?

1. There are multiple derived classes from Parent
2. `bar()` will not necessarily know which of the derived classes is passed in
3. The caller of `bar()` will not know which derived class function signature to pass in

**EDIT**

I know of one way to do this, but I see it as a little hacky:

```
def bar(passed_in_func):
  temp = [DerivedA(), DerivedB()]
  for derived in temp:
    getattr(derived, passed_in_func)()

bar('foo')
```

Comment: If you pass a derived class **`instance`** as an argument to a `bar()` function (not the one in your code), then it can just do: `instance.foo()` and the right class' method will be called.

Comment: yes that is one way to do it, albeit one of my requirements was that `bar()` will not necessarily know which of the derived classes is passed in, which implicitly invalidates passing in the derived class instance into `bar()`. The function `bar()` does the actual lookup and/or accessing of the derived class.

Comment: How about getting the name by `funcName = passed_in_func.__name__` and then `getattr(derived, funcName)()`. Though, is still quite strange...I think.

Comment: Couldn't you just pass `bar()` the `foo` method of the appropriate subclass instance i.e. `DerivedA().foo`, `DerivedB().foo`, etc? Seems like you're trying to re-invent the built-in way methods are normally dispatched to subclasses in OOP.

Comment: @martineau the caller of `bar` does not know the specific derived class, just that it contains `foo`. `bar` acts as an interface to calling `foo` on the derived class in my scenario. The derived class can technically be passed in as a parameter of `bar`, but I would like to avoid that since it would lead to a lot of code repetition.

Comment: @MatrixTai that is an improvement on my edit, but I’m hoping for a cleaner solution than using `getattr` if it js possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a generic way of doing it that would work for immediate subclasses:

```
class Parent:
    def foo(self):
        print('parent')


class DerivedA(Parent):
    def foo(self):
        print('derived A')


class DerivedB(Parent):
    def foo(self):
        print('derived B')


def bar(passed_in_func):
    classname = passed_in_func.__qualname__.split('.')[0]
    parent = eval(classname)
    for derived in parent.__subclasses__():
        getattr(derived(), passed_in_func.__name__)()

bar(Parent.foo)
```

Output:

```
derived A
derived B
```

Comment: Yes this can work, although the iteration over the parent's subclasses is not needed, I just used a list of the subclasses in `bar()` to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example. This is the solution I ended up using, but I'm still hoping for something cleaner to come along, but I'm not sure there is one.

Comment: ajoseps: I had the subclasses hardcoded in an earlier version, but decided the code would be more re-usable if it wasn't tied to some specific class hierarchy, and the cost of making it more generic was very low—although to be honest I don't see this pattern as getting reused very often.